# Is there a smart way in Python to check if a input value match one of the class variables?

Tags: python, dry

Here is a naive implementation.

```py
class DataFormat:
    CP2K_OUTPUT_DIR = 'cp2k/output_dir'
    VASP_OUTPUT_DIR = 'vasp/output_dir'
    LAMMPS_OUTPUT_DIR = 'lammps/output_dir'

    CP2K_OUTPUT = 'cp2k/output'
    VASP_OUTPUT = 'vasp/xml'
    EXTXYZ = 'extxyz'


    @classmethod
    def is_valid(cls, format: str):
        return format in [
            cls.CP2K_OUTPUT_DIR,
            cls.VASP_OUTPUT_DIR,
            cls.LAMMPS_OUTPUT_DIR,
            cls.CP2K_OUTPUT,
            cls.VASP_OUTPUT,
            cls.EXTXYZ,
        ]
```

Is there a smart way to implement `is_valid` so that I don't need to update it when a new data format is supported?

Comment: You could always create a `valid_list` as a class variable.  There has to be a list somewhere.

Comment: That's what I am doing now. Just wonder if there any magic method to simplify it?

Comment: try `return format in [ v for k,v in vars(cls).items() if not k.startswith('__')]`